# When I am using XAML does it inherit properties like color?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I have this code:

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:HOV Grid.Row="0" />
    <local:HST Grid.Row="1" />
    <local:HAC Grid.Row="2" />
    <local:HAI Grid.Row="3" />
</Grid>
```

and I want to set the color of the text in everything inside the grid can I just specify:

```
TextColor="Gray"
```

in the  and then everything inside there will be Gray color?

Comment: No, each XAML element becomes a concrete instance object at runtime and there is no object inheritance taking placing, there are *containers* such as Grid, StackLayout, etc.. and if you assign a background color to it, any parts of  a ViewElement that do not cover the grid *could* show that color (depends upon the how that platform-dependent view draws itself) or if you explicitly set that ViewElement to have a Clear/transparent background then the container's color shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid doesn't support the TextColor property. You can use an implicit style and color all the labels on a content page like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

You can create a named style like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="lblStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And apply it to a label like this:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource lblStyle}" Text="Test" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You will either have to create an implicit style or set the color to gray as default on your inherited controls.